# How to implement a delegation using cglib?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, cglib

Here I required to create a instance of `BImpl` but `BImpl` requires to access functionality by an interface `A`. For this purpose, the class implements this interface `A`. How Can I wire a delegation of these interface methods of `BImpl` at runtime ? The idea is that `BImpl` can use `A`'s methods.

In my case `A` is known and the `AImpl` instance is created at run-time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  B b = (B) Enhancer.create(BImpl.class, new MyInterceptor());
  System.out.println(b.cellValue());
}

interface A {
  String value();
}

class AImpl implements A {

  @Override
  public String value() {
    return "MyA";
  }
}

interface B {
  String cellValue();
}

abstract class BImpl implements B, A {
  @Override
  public String cellValue() {
    return value() + "MyBCell";
  }
}

class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

  @Override
  public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
                          MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
    if ("value".equals(method.getName()))
      return method.invoke(obj, args);
    else
      return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a *mixin* pattern. Can you not simply implement a delegation explicitly? Something like:

```
class BImpl implements B, A {

  private A a;

  public BImpl(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  @Override
  public String cellValue() {
    return value() + "MyBCell";
  }

  @Override
  public String value() {
    return a.value();
  }
}
```

This should be possible since you say that you know `A` during compilation.

Otherwise, your approach is probably the correct one for cglib if you are really need to do this at runtime. However, you need to hand a different instance for `obj` when calling:

```
return method.invoke(obj, args);
```

Otherwise you call the intercepted method again and find yourself in an endless loop by hitting `MyMethodInterceptor` in a loop. You could also [safe yourself the branch and use a `CallbkackFilter` instead](http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2013/11/cglib-missing-manual.html).

If you are not bound to cglib, you could also look into my library [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net) which makes this all a little bit more expressive:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(BImpl.class)
  .method(isAnnotatedBy(A.class))
  .intercept(Forwarding.to("a", A.class))
  .make();
```

The generated class has now a field `a` which you can set to an instance of any `A` to which the method invocations of the `A` interface methods are now delegated. You can set this field by for example using Java reflection. Otherwise, you can use a `static` field by

```
Forwarding.to(new A() {
  // A methods
});
```